# Hyperelliptic Riemann surfaces

Tags: differential-forms, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I have been reading Rick Miranda's Book on Riemann surfaces and now he introduces the concept of Hyperelliptic Riemann surfaces . My doubt is when he claims that the map $x$ on $X$ extends to a meromorphic map $\pi : Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ of degree $2$ and with branch points the roots of $h(x)$ ( and the point $\infty$ if $h$ has odd degree). How is this extension done how do we define the function for the points in $Y$ that are not in $X$, do we just send them to $\infty$? (these points are just the points of the form $(0,w)$), is this the correct way to the extension of the funciton, does he mention anywhere how he extends the function?

Also the last one regarding $\infty$, i cant seem to see why the fact that $h$ having odd degree would have to do with this fact, in fact what is $\pi^{-1}(\infty)$? I have a feeling that it is going to be the point of $Y$ where $z=0$ but i cant seem to prove it i guess the fact that $h$ has odd degree comes into play because then we will have a point where $w^2=0$ and that will be "bad".

So any help figuring this out or giving me some hints would be nice.Also isnt the function $x$ on $X$ also holomorphic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How the extension of $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_\infty$ to $Z$ is defined ? My confusion is elements of $Z$ if the form $\{(x,y),\phi(x,y)\}$ and $\{\phi^{-1}(z,w),(z,w)\}$. How to define the map for this kind of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about how Miranda is extending the map $x$ to $Y$, but I don't think this is explicitly mentioned anywhere; it's implicitly implied by an extension of the isomorphism $(x,y)\mapsto (1/x,y/x^{g+1})$.

When the degree is odd, so that $h(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2g+1$, then $k(z) = z^{2g+2}h(1/z)$ has $z=0$ as a root. This means that $(0,0)$ is the only point of $Y\setminus V$ and since $(0,0)\mapsto \infty$ under $x$, we will have a branch point at $\infty$. On the other hand, if $h(x)$ was of degree $2g+2$, then $k(z)$ wouldn't have $z=0$ as a root, so that $Y\setminus V$ would be two distinct points $(0,\sqrt{k(z)})$ and $(0,-\sqrt{k(z)})$, preventing $\infty$ from being a branch point.

Comment: Is hyper elliptic curves kind of compactification of affine algebraic curves?

Comment: How the extension of $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_\infty$ to $Z$ is defined ? My confusion is elements of $Z$ if the form $\{(x,y),\phi(x,y)\}$ and $\{\phi^{-1}(z,w),(z,w)\}$. How to define the map for this kind of points.